# Are there any clear explanations for these trends?

Tags: word-usage

I was curious earlier about the use of various pronouns / possessives in English (primarily first person), so I chose a selection of them and was surprised to discover that, among other oddities, ["I" has apparently undergone a rather drastic shift in use over the last century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%2Cme%2Cwe%2Cus%2Cour%2Cmine%2Cmy%2Cours%2Courselves%2Cmyself%2Cyou%2Cthey&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Courselves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmyself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%3B%2Cc0). I was wondering whether any further statistical analysis of usage had been done to describe these trends. Specifically, whether there's any statistical (so, not anecdotal or simply convincing-sounding) explanation for what patterns of use of the word might be responsible?

What constructions fell out of use so markedly? What constructions have been revived, and which new ones are most responsible?

P.S: This **may** be too broad a question, but since (as per the help center) it does appear to fall under the site's remit, I thought I might as well ask. Plus, my own research was getting me nowhere; somewhat unsurprisingly, adding the most common words in the language to a search string doesn't really narrow down results significantly.

Comment: I really wonder about whether this is an artifact of the sort of books Google Books indexes.

Comment: @MattGutting And what sorts of books are kept in the libraries from which GB is drawn.

Comment: @MattGutting That's certainly a possibility, or it could be there were just way more textbooks written in the '60s. I assumed it wasn't the former simply because going from 0.45 to 0.3 seemed like too huge a shift to be sampling error, but then again, maybe not.

Comment: I don't think there's enough of a trend to tell much.  Remember that the mix of books scanned will vary over the years, potentially changing the "tone" of what's scanned.  And, in any event, if the change is real it hardly qualifies as "drastic".

Comment: @HotLicks What is drastic [depends on the order of magnitude you're working within](http://attrition.org/misc/ee/99.9-percent-correct.txt), and the expected trend over time. If a word's frequency only varies by about 0.05 around a given value for 150 years, and then in a 50 year period slides down monotonically by 0.15 percent, then slides up monotonically over the next 50 years back to where it was, I'd say that's drastic. Realistically, "I" is never going to be every 20th word. You might be right about what gets scanned being significantly skewed, though.

Comment: An apparent change in frequency of less than 2x can hardly be considered "drastic", especially when the level still does not rise to historic highs.  I've seen many Ngrams with similar fluctuations over the last 50 years or so.

Comment: @HotLicks That's fair. I suppose there's a nontrivial degree to which it depends on your definition of "significant". Although it also depends on the initial frequency of a word; "I" is extremely common, so I'd expect a change by 1.5x to be more significant statistically than even a 4x change in a word like ["prestidigitation"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prestidigitation&year_start=1700&year_end=2008), simply because there are more instances where it could be used to begin with.

Comment: Consider that, in the past 50 years, the nature of publishing has changed dramatically -- self-publishing, e-publishing, "graphic novels", etc.

Comment: Not an artifact but an influence (to a significant extent) of English Fiction https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%2Cme%2Cwe%2Cus%2Cour%2Cmine%2Cmy%2Cours%2Courselves%2Cmyself%2Cyou%2Cthey&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=16&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Courselves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmyself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%3B%2Cc0 can be suspected.